# Is it possible to upload .mlmodel files over wifi insetad of having them embedded?

Tags: ios, machine-learning, models, coreml

I'm planning to use some models with over 500MB size and I don't want them embedded otherwise my app will be huge which is not really desirable.

Thanks,

Comment: So now users need to download a 500 MB data file after installing the app? I'm not sure that's an improvement…

Comment: Well, at least they are not forced to. They will download the file only when they are keen to use say object detection feature.

Comment: I'd seriously reconsider your network design in this case. There's no reason to use networks that large. You can get just as good, if not better, accuracies by using a different network architecture. SqueezeNet-based networks can be smaller than 5 MB in size, yet outperform the 500 MB+ networks in terms of accuracy. You'll be wasting a lot of user bandwidth for no reason.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is possible. After downloading the model, [compile](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coreml/mlmodel/2921516-compilemodel) it using:

```
let compiledUrl = try MLModel.compileModel(at: modelUrl)
let model = try MLModel(contentsOf: compiledUrl)
```

The compiled model will be stored in a temporary location. After compilation completes, you should move it to a permanent location.